# Missing hostname connecting Proxy via AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, nginx, proxy, elastic-load-balancer

Im trying to get web page through some servers below

Client→Load Balancer→Proxy(EC2)

but when request passed from Load Balancer to Proxy, hostname was missing.

any advice will helps me, thank you.

Connect directly from client to Proxy

`[04/Apr/2018:07:24:09 +0000] "GET http://abehiroshi.la.coocan.jp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3770 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" "-"`

・When Connect to Proxy via Load balancer(http://abehiroshi.la.coocan.jp)is missing

`[04/Apr/2018:07:14:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3770 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Which type of load balancer, specifically, is this? Classic ELB in HTTP mode, or Application Load Balancer?

Comment: Thank you for your reaction.
I'm using Application Load Balancer now.

Answer (score 0):

Application Load Balancer isn't designed to work in front of a forward web proxy (alternately sometimes called simply a "web proxy" -- which seems to be what you are running in EC2, and Is consistent with requests in the form shown).

ALB is a reverse proxy, intended to be placed in front of origin servers or other reverse proxies (sometimes configured in tiers).  It won't work for this use case.

For this application, you need either a Network Load Balancer (NLB), or a Classic ELB in TCP (not HTTP) mode.  An NLB is the preferred solution.

Comment: It works by NLB. Thanks a lot !! I really appreciate it.